# SQLiteOpenHelper constructor is not being called

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am creating an app using the `SQLiteOpenHelper`. When I create an object for this class, the constructor is not being called which results in a `NullPointerException` when I use it's methods. Here is my `DatabaseHandler` class:

```
class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "INVENTORY_MANAGER";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "INVENTORY";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_ITEM_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_ITEM_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String KEY_ITEM_COUNT = "count";
    private static final String KEY_ITEM_SOLD = "sold";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(final SQLiteDatabase db) {
        final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME
                + "( " + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + KEY_ITEM_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_ITEM_PRICE + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_ITEM_COUNT + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_ITEM_SOLD + " TEXT )";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(final SQLiteDatabase db, final int oldVersion, final int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    void addItem(final Item item) {
        final SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        final ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_ITEM_NAME, item.getItemName());
        contentValues.put(KEY_ITEM_PRICE, item.getItemPrice());
        contentValues.put(KEY_ITEM_COUNT, item.getItemCount());
        contentValues.put(KEY_ITEM_SOLD, item.getItemSold());
        long id = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        Log.i("LOG", "" + id);
        db.close();
    }

    List<Item> getItems() {
        final List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        final String SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        final SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        final Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SELECT_QUERY, null);
        if ( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
            do {
                final Item item = new Item();
                item.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                item.setItemName(cursor.getString(1));
                item.setItemPrice(cursor.getString(2));
                item.setItemCount(cursor.getString(3));
                item.setItemSold(cursor.getString(4));
            } while ( cursor.moveToNext() );
        }
        cursor.close();
        return items;
    }
}
```

This is the code in my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private List<Item> items;
   private ItemsListAdapter adapter;
   private DatabaseHandler handler;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState, final PersistableBundle persistentState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   items = new ArrayList<>();
   final View emptyView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_empty, null, false);
   addContentView(emptyView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
   final ListView itemList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemList);
   handler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
   items.addAll(handler.getItems());
   adapter = new ItemsListAdapter(items, getApplicationContext());
   if (itemList != null) {
                    itemList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    itemList.setEmptyView(emptyView);
                    itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, final long id) {
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_add_item) {
                    final View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_item, null);
                    final EditText addItemName = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.addItemName);
                    final EditText addItemPrice = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.addItemPrice);
                    final EditText addItemCount = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.addItemCount);
                    final EditText addItemSold = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.addItemSold);
                    final AlertDialog.Builder itemAdder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(MainActivity.this, R.style.Dialog));
                    itemAdder.setTitle("Add Item");
                    itemAdder.setMessage("Enter details about the new item");
                    itemAdder.setView(dialogView);
                    itemAdder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                            final Item item = new Item();
                            final String itemName = addItemName.getText().toString().trim();
                            String itemPrice = addItemPrice.getText().toString().trim();
                            String itemCount = addItemCount.getText().toString().trim();
                            String itemSold = addItemSold.getText().toString().trim();

                                    item.setItemName(itemName);
                                    item.setItemPrice(itemPrice);
                                    item.setItemCount(itemCount);
                                    item.setItemSold(itemSold);

    //This is where I get the error
    /*java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List aakaashjois.inventoryapp.DatabaseHandler.addItem(item)' on a null object reference */
                                    handler.addItem(item);
                                    items.clear();
                                    items.addAll(handler.getItems());
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            }

                    });
                    itemAdder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    itemAdder.create().show();
                    return true;
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
```

Here is my log when I get the error:

```
06-15 11:46:11.880 29965-29980/aakaashjois.inventoryapp I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1717(388KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 1579KB/2MB, paused 10.377ms total 30.998ms
06-15 11:46:11.904 29965-29965/aakaashjois.inventoryapp I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
06-15 11:46:19.049 29965-29965/aakaashjois.inventoryapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-15 11:46:19.051 29965-29965/aakaashjois.inventoryapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: aakaashjois.inventoryapp, PID: 29965
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void aakaashjois.inventoryapp.DatabaseHandler.addItem(aakaashjois.inventoryapp.Item)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at aakaashjois.inventoryapp.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:108)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
06-15 11:46:19.115 29965-29965/aakaashjois.inventoryapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 29965 SIG: 9
```

Based on the feedback I received, I removed the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class and wrote the SQLite syntax without that class. The application runs with no problems now. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: show your logcat..!!

Comment: I have added the logcat

Comment: you are not getting error at `handler.getItems()` very first line after `handler = new DatabaseHandler(this);` ??

Comment: Nope. That line runs fine. Error comes only when I try to add items.

Comment: That means your constructor has no problem the problem is with `addItems`   method. put a break point inside that as well as on this line `handler.addItem(item);` and debug the app. You will find the exact problem..!!

Comment: But I have put a Log inside the constructor and that does not get printed in Logcat.

Comment: i think you have put it after `super(..)`. Put it before `super()`..!!

Comment: It does not allow me to put anything before super(). So I put the Log.i() inside the onCreate and all the other methods. Even getItems(). I set break points and tried running. Still, none of the Logs got printed.

Comment: So there is some problem with all logs try restarting android studio run project again.. There is some problem in your `addItems()` method if ANY..!!

Comment: Restarting did not work. I'll try to run the same code on different version of Android Studio with different version of build tools, platform tools and sdk version.

Comment: `SQLiteOpenHelper` `onCreate()` is run only once when the database didn't exist. That's why you don't see it in logs. The problem that causes the NPE is that the `handler` reference is null for some reason. What's the API level you're running on? Note that `Activity#onCreate(Bundle, PersistableBundle)` is API level 21+ and it won't get invoked below API 21.

Comment: I am trying on API level 23 and API level 21 devices.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class called `DatabaseAdapter`. Add the following code to it:

```
public class DatabaseAdapter {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "INVENTORY_MANAGER";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "INVENTORY";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_ITEM_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_ITEM_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String KEY_ITEM_COUNT = "count";
    private static final String KEY_ITEM_SOLD = "sold";

    private Context context;
    SQLiteDatabase database;
    DatabaseHelper helper;

    public DatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    this.helper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME
                    + "( " + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                    + KEY_ITEM_NAME + " TEXT, "
                    + KEY_ITEM_PRICE + " TEXT, "
                    + KEY_ITEM_COUNT + " TEXT, "
                    + KEY_ITEM_SOLD + " TEXT)");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w("Database", “Upgrading database from version “ +     oldVersion + “ to “ + newVersion + “, which will destroy all old data”);
           db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
           onCreate(db);
       }
   }

    public DatabaseAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        this.database = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        DatabaseHelper.close();
    }

    public long addItem(final Item item) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(KEY_ITEM_NAME, item.getItemName());
        contentValues.put(KEY_ITEM_PRICE, item.getItemPrice());
        contentValues.put(KEY_ITEM_COUNT, item.getItemCount());
        contentValues.put(KEY_ITEM_SOLD, item.getItemSold());

        return database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }

    // Add the rest of your code here
}
```

In your main activity, you can now reference your `DatabaseAdapter` class as so:

```
DatabaseAdapter database = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
database.open();

// call any of the functions that you need
long insert = database.addItem(Item parametre);

database.close();
```

Also, have a look at [this](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj1x6yKzanNAhVGHZQKHbIMBJcQFgg4MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww3.ul.ie%2Fictlc%2FAndroid.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEnl42PbQmfmdeOvz5bGxEve5P4VA&sig2=-ItwroFYzg3H1fpT_uUc_w&bvm=bv.124272578,d.dGo) eBook which has an etire section on SQLite databases. This could also resolve your issue.

Comment: I think it's because of the left over code that you have that the `DatabaseHelper` class now takes care of for you. I will update the answer with the new code.

Comment: Have a look at the new `addItem` function. It will automatically return a `long` value. You will have to initialise a `long` variable and then call the function to add an item.

Comment: Are you getting the error from the `getItems` function? If you are, then you will need to tweak it also.

Comment: The `getItems` function does not give any error. The Log code I placed inside it does not generate any output in Logcat either.

Comment: You could try uninstall the app and reinstall it or clear all of your app's data via Settings. Then open the app and try add an item. Tell me if you're still getting the error.

Comment: I have done that many times on the devices. I end up with the same error. Could it be a problem with Android Studio? I tried it on 2.2 Preview and 2.1 stable version. I end up with the same error. I tried with Java 1.6 and Java 1.8, still no luck. Maybe I should just delete the project and start writing from scratch again and see if anything changes.

Comment: You could. I also had those problems when I got `NullPointerException`s with my database. Your issue seems strange. Usually, it's fixed quickly but there's something going on internally that I can't see. The code I provided you might be a good start if you're planning to restart your project.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try the whole thing again and get back with the results.